# handler404 returning Server Error (500) instead of 404.html - Django/Python

Tags: python, django

I spent several hours on this code and could not get to find out why I am getting server error (500) instead of 404.html in django program. Please see below codes and could someone help?

```
settings.py: 
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

urls.py: (app is mysite)
handler404 = "mysite.views.error_404"

views.py: 
def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html')
404.html:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block main %}

some html text here

{% endblock %}
```

Error message from log:
[image]

Comment: Is there definitely an app in your project called `mysite`?

Comment: Also, can you add the error traceback from the runserver?

Comment: Yes, my app is called mysite.

Comment: could you fix this problem ?

Comment: I've the same error...

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of all the extend commands from your 404 page and render a plain HTML page with no Django extends.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've been having a similar problem that I spent days on. Not sure why yet, but when I cleared my 404.html page and just wrote "a simple 404", the 404 started to work again. I guess I did something with my template incorrect

Answer (score 1):

I got the same 500 error and figure it out where it went wrong, the 404.html is not loading correctly because it doesn't know where to get that from in main urls.py, In settings

TEMPLATES = [

...

'DIRS' = [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],

...

]

[image: Settings]

the BASE_DIR is in pathlib format just added templates like shown in the image below

[image: Templates location]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path of the 404 file:

```
def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'mysite/404.html') # Instead of only '404.html'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but it still show server 500.